# Jwt authorization/ passport

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

Hello I have a question about JWT, auth:

I created my auth class:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const Strategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

module.exports = (app) => {
    const jwtConfig = app.config.jwt;
    const Users = app.datasource.models.tb_users;
    const options = {};

    options.secretOrKey = jwtConfig.secret;
    options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();

    const strategy = new Strategy(options,(payload, done) => {

        Users
        .findOne({where: payload.id})
        .then(user => {

            if(user){
                return done(null,{
                    id: user.id,
                    login: user.login
                });
            }
            return done(null,false);
        })
        .catch(error => done(error,null));

    });

    passport.use(strategy);
    return {
        initialize: () => passport.initialize(),
        authenticate: () => passport.authenticate('jwt', jwtConfig.session)
    };
}
```

this is my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth');

const authorization = require('./auth');

const config = require('./config/config');
const datasource = require('./config/datasource');

const Email = require('./utils/email');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set('port',port);
app.config = config;
app.email = new Email(app.config);
app.datasource = datasource(app);

console.log(app.config);

app.use(bodyParser.json({
limit: '5mb'
}));

const auth = authorization(app);
app.use(auth.initialize());
app.auth = auth;

indexRouter(app);
usersRouter(app);
authRouter(app);

module.exports = app;
```

And then I have my token login and validation method

```
app.route('/login')
    .post(async (req,res)=>{
        try {
            const response = await usersControllers.signin(req.body);
            const login = response.login;
            console.log(login);
            if(login.id && login.isValid){
                const payload = {id: login.id};
                res.json({
                    token: jwt.sign({data:payload}, app.config.jwt.secret,{expiresIn: '1h'})
                });
            }else{
                console.log('entrou here');
                res.sendStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            } 
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('entrou here');
            console.error(error.message);
            res.sendStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    })
```

and in my method of searching all users I call this authorization:

```
app.route('/users')
    .all(app.auth.authenticate())
    .get((req,res)=>{
        usersController
            .getAll()
            .then(data => {
                res.json(data);
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                console.log(error);
                res.status(400);
            });

    })
```

here: .all(app.auth.authenticate())

At this point I start to get confused
in insomnia he if I go in the login route and then in the get all users route he gives unauthorized even though being authorized by the login route

I would like to know what I could do so I could use my get route with my token
Is this front end work?

Basically I would like to know how I would do to access other routes with my token other than insomnia

And what I could improve on my code is missing something to achieve this?

Comment: **...get confused in insomnia...**  **...other than insomnia...** what do you mean by this? And how does your request look like? Did you provide the `Authorization` header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly clear what is being asked and you are referencing "insomnia" which is not represented in the code you have shared. You have asked about the token work on the frontend and will share some thoughts.

You need to save the token on the client when it is returned from **POST** to `/login`. As you have specified the that passport should attempt to extract the token from the request headers: `options.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();` you will need to send the token within your headers when you are attempting to access secured routes. This is added as key/value to "Authorization" in the format "Bearer " + token.

For example using chaihttp test runner to post data to a secured route:

```
            chai.request(server)
                .post(`/books`)
                .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.token}`) // set the auth header with the token
                .send(data)
                ...
```

Comment: I was wrong insomnia, 
I managed to get my client to save jwt, but I'm having trouble validating this client jwt for use on another route.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3Yd0zH5r 
If you can take a look to help me out I send my token from my client side but I can't validate on my back end I don't know why

Comment: Post a new question and I can look at that part of it there

Comment: thanks bro i post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847651/jwt-validation-in-sessionstorage-react-in-backend if u can help, thanks.