# Jwt validation in sessionStorage react in backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

I have an api that I consume to login and generate a JWT
operating normally, I save my jwt in a sessionStorage:

```
getDate = () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token')));
        const data = {token: sessionStorage.getItem('token')};
        const requestInfo = {
            method:'GET',
            body: JSON.stringify({data}),
            headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'jwt': sessionStorage.getItem('token')
            }),
        };
        console.log('chegouaq');
        fetch('http://localhost:9000/users', requestInfo)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('chegouaq2');
            if(response.ok){
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error("Token Invalido..")
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            return;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            this.setState({message: e.message})
            console.error(e);
        });
    }
```

I send my jwt through head, but I'm having trouble and I don't know how to validate it with my API

my router /users:

```
app.route('/users')
        .all(app.auth.authenticate())
        .get((req,res)=>{
            usersController
                .getAll()
                .then(data => {
                    res.json(data);
                })
                .catch(error=>{
                    console.log(error);
                    res.status(400);
                });
    })
```

> .all(app.auth.authenticate())

Here I call my passport strategy

and this is my strategy:

```
const strategy = new Strategy(options,(payload, done) => {

        Users
        .findOne({where: payload.id})
        .then(user => {

            if(user){
                return done(null,{
                    id: user.id,
                    login: user.login
                });
            }
            return done(null,false);
        })
        .catch(error => done(error,null));

    });

    passport.use(strategy);
    return {
        initialize: () => passport.initialize(),
        authenticate: () => passport.authenticate('jwt', jwtConfig.session)
    };
}
```

I don't know how I will send my jwt to validate

my main app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth');

const authorization = require('./auth');

const config = require('./config/config');
const datasource = require('./config/datasource');

const Email = require('./utils/email');

const app = express();
const port = 9000;

app.set('port',port);
app.config = config;
app.email = new Email(app.config);
app.datasource = datasource(app);

console.log(app.config);

app.use(bodyParser.json({
limit: '5mb'
}));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
const auth = authorization(app);
app.use(auth.initialize());
app.auth = auth;

indexRouter(app);
usersRouter(app);
authRouter(app);

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the Authorization header as follows:

```
  headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
            }),
```

Comment: I tried to change this, but I still have these errors:  index.js:14 OPTIONS http://localhost:9000/users 401 (Unauthorized),  Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9000/users' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: OK, that's a CORS issue, not JWT at this stage. You are posting from localhost:3000 to localhost:9000 - is there a reason or is that a typo in code?

Comment: I do not think so
i was having the same cors problem with my route / login
but I added this to my app.js

app.use (function (req, res, next) {
    res.header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next ();
  });

Comment: Can you confirm what port the express app is running on

Comment: yes I edited the question and put my main .app it is running on port 9000

Comment: I don't know maybe I need to put something in my header about:
 res.header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next ();

Comment: Can you change the fetch url in your view to: fetch('/users', requestInfo)

Comment: Now it came to my api, but I received this error:
index.js: 1375 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <in JSON at position 0

Comment: here in return obtain this error :  .then(response => {
            console.log('chegouadasdq2');
            if(response.ok){
                console.log('chegouadasdqdasd2');
                return response.json();
            }

Comment: The problem now seems to be your data being passed in. Don't stringify  JSON.stringify({data}), just pass the data object

Comment: It still doesn't hit my api, I tested it on my api and it's not there, the problem is in response i gave a console.log in it

Comment: It is going to: url: "http: // localhost: 3000 / xdusers"
and no to:

url: "http: // localhost: 9000 / xdusers"

Comment: Then your express server must be running on 3000

Comment: There are too many issues here and not enough clarity on the environment. I have provided the answer to your question: "I don't know how I will send my jwt to validate" Now it confirms that you have a CORS issue as you are posting from another domain via react which was not clear. Here is some content to research: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: With the cors worked, sorry for the inconvenience, I on my route took my validation:

        .all (app.auth.authenticate ())

and got my all use

Comment: In my back end I could find my jwt:
    authorization: headers: {
    host: 'localhost: 9000',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    authorization: 'Bearer "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7ImlkIjo2fSwiaWF0IjoxNTczNjkyNzIyLCJleHA1mLJj9m3J3j3
    origin: 'http: // localhost: 3000',

Comment: Great, good luck with the rest. Please mark the answer correct if it solved the question: "I don't know how I will send my jwt to validate" so other users can find solutions easily.